# Can we Configure Change Data Capture in another Database?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to apply Change Data Capture(CDC) to database DB1's tables and want to log everything in DB2.

So, could it be possible to capture table DB1's changes to DB2?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible

According to MSDN

> All objects that are associated with a capture instance are created in the change data capture schema of the enabled database.

[About Change Data Capture (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way like using Triggers and all Is is Possible to do the required ??

Comment: Yes, you can use triggers to audit db events and store the captured data in another db. You can find an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357483/creating-triggers-to-add-the-data-into-audit-table