# MySQL: How to find out which records were deleted in a cascading delete

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 40+ tables in my project and i have applied cascade delete with all the constraints. now my database has real time data so i just want to get track of deletion happening because of cascade delete.

so basically i just want to know that if i delete any one user from user table (user has relation with 10+ tables) then from which all are table and which data has deleted.

so i can record them in one another file just for backup purpose.

is there any way in mysql?

Comment: IMHO this is a job for [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357483/creating-triggers-to-add-the-data-into-audit-table)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use on delete triggers for all the tables that are involved into the cascade constraint, this constraint will operate on the child table as a simple insert or delete will.

Comment: Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers (in MySQL)

Comment: For reference from the documentation see [FOREIGN KEY Constraints - Referential Actions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions) *"Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers."*