# Mysql/PHP UPDATE the table + INSERT INTO an other table

Tags: php, mysql

Can I copy something to an other table and also update this in the same table?

Like:

```
INSERT INTO 'table_new' (name) values ("thomas")
```

At the same time:

```
UPDATE 'table_old' set ChangesWereMadeAt = (the date, where the changes were made)
```

Can I put something in other table, while it stays also in the old table and just updates one column ?

I work with PHP/MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `LAST_INSERT_ID();`

```
INSERT INTO 'table_new' (name) values ("thomas");
$last_id_inserted = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 

UPDATE 'table_old' SET blah='$blah' WHERE id='$last_id_inserted';
```

Answer (score 0):

Begin by inserting your new line into your table.

Then delete the line from the first table.

And finally copy the line you inserted with this:

```
INSERT INTO first_table
SELECT *
FROM dues
WHERE id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Like: INSERT INTO 'table_new' (name) values ("thomas")
>
> At the same time:
>
> UPDATE 'table_old' set ChangesWereMadeAt = (the date, where the
>   changes were made)

Based on this, I'd say the solution would be to make two requests.

> This means... Can I put something in an other table while it stays also in the old table and just updates one column ?

But based on this, I could give a sort of solution.

```
$reqSelect= 'select * from YourTable 
where [insert the condition that would make you select only the data you want to copy]';
$data = mysqli_query($connection, $reqSelect);

$reqInsert='insert into YourDestinationTable(row1, row2, etc)
values('.$data[row1].', '.$data[row2].', '.$data[etc]);
mysqli_query($connection, $reqInsert);

$reqUpdate='update YourTable where [conditions here]
set TheRowYouWantToModify = '.data[TheDataYouWantInYourRow];
mysqli_query($connection, $reqUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would be easier to solved my a MySql trigger. There is a basic example here: [Creating Triggers to add the data into Audit Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357483/creating-triggers-to-add-the-data-into-audit-table)