# c# .net mysql - Best way to find an updated row in one million row table

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I query a MySQL table in my c# console app. Thousands of updates(row) are coming in all the times via another program and I want to propagate them, let's say for an easy way Console.WriteLine, in the fastest possible way (almost instantly). See diagram.

[MYSQL to C# updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEvLO.png)

Where do I do it in the most efficient/fastest way? On the MySQL Server? Or in my c# script?

If in my c# sript, do I use lists to compare old vs new row, or arrays? Any other way?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any DateTime based column in your table which modifies in each update?

Comment: You might want to look at TRIGGERS ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html
I would definitely detect the changes in SQL and only propagate the changes to your C#.

Comment: @Rob ok, I had a look into TRIGGERS. From what I have understood, it tells inside the MySQL server that something has been done and then executes a certain command. So how can I receive the updated rows in my C# program? I failed to find that answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use triggers to write audit tables

There are some pretty good guides and questions on this like this: [Creating Triggers to add the data into Audit Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357483/creating-triggers-to-add-the-data-into-audit-table)

It does not contain timestamps which would be required for your case and it would also need a lot of space in your database to store all these changes

Comment: thanks. So basically, I can make a new table and call it to queue and each time I pull that table, I delete the content of it?

Is there a way to kinda lock this at that moment, so if new updates are coming in, they won't get lost?

Comment: You can add a timestamp for each entry, and delete up to the processed timestamp.

Comment: right, thanks. I think this is the best way forward for me.